# ByteArray convert to String with UTF-8 charset in kotlin problem

Tags: string, kotlin, utf-8, byte

i have a little confused

```
// default charset utf8
val bytes = byteArrayOf(78, 23, 41, 51, -32, 42)
val str = String(bytes)
// there i got array [78, 23, 41, 51, -17, -65, -67, 42]
val weird = str.toByteArray()
```

i put random value into the bytes property, for some reason. why is it inconsistent???

Comment: `[-17, -65, -67]` array (hexadecimal `0xEF,0xBF,0xBD`) is Byte Order Mark (UTF-8)  (appears as `ï¿½` in latin1).

Comment: @JosefZ No, that's `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`.

Comment: My bad. In fact,  `[-17, -65, -67]` byte array (hexadecimal `0xEF,0xBF,0xBD`)  which appears as `ï¿½` in latin1 is   �  `U+FFFD`    *Replacement Character*. Thanks @AlexeyRomanov: *Byte Order Mark* is different: `U+FEFF`   (hexa `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`, latin1  `ï»¿`)  *Zero Width No-Break Space*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that your bytes aren't a valid [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_sequences_and_error_handling) sequence.

Any sequence of bytes can be interpreted as valid [ISO Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), for example.  (There may be issues with bytes having values 0–31, but those generally don't stop the characters being stored and processed.)  Similar applies to most other 8-bit character sets.

But the same isn't true of UTF-8.  While all sequences of bytes in the range 1–127 are valid UTF-8 (and interpreted the same as they are in ASCII and most 8-bit encodings), bytes in the range 128–255 can only appear in certain [well-defined combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding).  (This has several very useful properties: it lets you identify UTF-8 with a very high probability; it also avoids issues with synchronisation, searching, sorting, &c.)

In this case, the sequence in the question (which is `4E 17 29 33 E0 2A` in unsigned hex) isn't valid UTF-8.

So when you try to convert it to a string using the default encoding (UTF-8), the JVM substitutes the [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) — value U+FFFD, which looks like this: `�` — in place of each invalid character.

Then, when you convert *that* back to UTF-8, you get the UTF-8 encoding of the replacment character, which is `EF BF BD`.  And if you interpret that as signed bytes, you get `-17 -65 -67` — as in the question.

So Kotlin/JVM is handling the invalid input as best it can.